# can os.path.join (or other python method) append a '/' automatically for the case of the directory?

Tags: python

The `os.path.join(a, b)` method will generate a string ending without '/' no matter it is a file or directory. Now, is there any way (or any other `os.path` method) to get a '/' automatically for the case of the directory?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no such function in `os.path`.  It's easy to code up yourself, though:

```
if os.path.isdir(path):
    path = os.path.join(path, "")
```

This will add a `/` if there isn't already one at the end of `path` in case it points to a directory.

Answer (score 7):

You can add the separator in your code as follows:

```
path = os.path.join(a,b)
if os.path.isdir(path):
    path += os.sep
```

Comment: @SvenMarnach Typo fixed. Thanks for you comment.